# how to disable Babel for some text

Tags: pdf, babel

I want to write this :

```
(username:password)
```

this :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}

\begin{document}
   (username:password)
\end{document}
```

give me :

```
(username :password) % there a space added by babel before ':'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english,frenchb]{babel}

\begin{document}
{\shorthandoff{:}%
 (username:password)}

\foreignlanguage{english}{(username:password)}   

(username:password)
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sur it work in my case. But if I want to write something that doesn't respect English nor French rules?

Comment: My example contains *two* possible solutions. Choose the one you like better or is better adapted to your case. If you don't want hyphenation at all you can also disable it completly.

Comment: Sorry I haven't understood your solution the first time!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Sometimes, a little text to explain the answer is useful :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want LaTeX to print text without formatting, you should use the `verbatim` environment. This environment will print exactly what you wrote, without any modifications.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
(username:password)
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image]